# populating input text fixed on change on selected dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am having an issue where i have to populate an input text field on specific dropdown select.

I want to populate `<input id=title>` with either; the value selected from a select element or the value in an `<input type="text"` element that has `<div data-autocomplete>` as its parent.

```
<div data-autocompelete>
<select>
   <option>January</option>
   <option>February</option>
   <option>March</option>
</select>
<div data-autocompelete>
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
<select>
   <option>abc</option>
   <option>cde</option>
   <option>efg</option>
</select>
<div data-autocompelete>
<select>
   <option>2013</option>
   <option>2012</option>
   <option>2011</option>
</select>
<div data-autocompelete>
<input type="text" id="foo"/>
<input type="text" id="title"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of those divs. They are not properly closed

Comment: do those div tags close after each select, or is this how you actually coded it? cos it looks as if the html is badly formed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of the divs are closed after the select and input elements.

This code should work for that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $(this).parents("div :data-autocomplete").each(function(){
            $("#title").val($("#foo").val() + selectedValue + $("#title").val());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it should not reset title everytime we select. It should concatenate. and input id="foo" should be part of it too.

Comment: and you want the value of "foo" to be first or second in the concatenation?

Comment: check now? . . .if you don't like the order you can just shuffle the strings around, I'm sure you can figure that out

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty unfinished and not exactly to the point.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beardyco/m83Ha/)

Is this sort of what you're looking for?

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var what = $(this).val();
    $('#title').val(what);
});
```

Comment: it should not reset title everytime we select. It should concatenate. and input id="foo" should be part of it too.